# How to get control data through the aspx side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `SqlDataSource`.

Now, It is vital I do this on the client side.

I have tried using this piece of code I saw on another post:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtConnectionString.Text %>')
```

Either way, this is what I am looking for:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString= [ textbox1.Text ] />
```

This is basically what I need to do. I need to access control data from the client side. Specifically I need to get a Telerik TextBox Text, I don't know if it's different from getting an asp textbox text but either way.

So how do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `document.getElementById('<%=txtConnectionString.ClientID%>').value`

Hopefully you are not actually storing the connection string client side? That is not good practice.

Comment: Every one who will use this website will already know the connection string, and the connection string value is set by the server. EDIT: Fixed the error it was something else

Comment: But when i use the same method for the SelectCommand,
I get this error:
Keyword not supported: 'document.getelementbyid('<%'.

Comment: Never mind just used @text as the command and set the real text as the parameter